# Google+ Pure Server Side Flow for Sign In (OAuth 2)

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-plus

Why Google+ pure server side flow for Sign In is not recommended? There is not enough details anywhere. I want to implement the pure server side flow for my webapp but after reading this I am not sure I should go ahead and do it. Why offer the option if it is not recommended?

https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/redirect-uri-flow

Answer (score 0):

markovuksanovic wrote:

"It seems like the only security advantage is that if using one-time code flow, browser component and server component of the client each get their own token. In pure server side flow, only server gets the token and web application flow only client gets the token. Sending token from client to server, and vice versa, exposes end user to a certain risk. Using one-time code flow there is no sending token from client <--> server and the risk of tokens being compromised is less."

[Copied from here...](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/68444/149652)